# div disappears when hovering over it

Tags: css

I want to add a div over an image and when the user put the mouse over the div, the div shows up, but when I move the mouse over the div it shows up for a second and then disappear.
**html code:**

```
<img src="image.png" id="image" />
<div id="div1">div1
<div id="div2">div2</div>
</div>
```

**css code:**

```
#image
{
display: block;
}
#div1
{
transition: opacity 1s;background-color: red;margin-top: -100px;opacity: 0;
}
#div1:hover
{
opacity: 1;
}
#div2
{
background-color: blue;
}
```

problem solved:
replaced `margin-top` with `position: relative`

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `transition: 1s opacity;` should be `transition: opacity 1s;` Edit: I stand corrected, it still works. I put your code in a JS fiddle and the line I had to delete to get it to work correctly was the `margin-top` (I don't have an image to add)

Comment: @Jhecht you can try out http://placehold.it/ for placeholder images

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x3a6frgx/ is this the behavior you're getting?

Comment: thanks @Jhecht, and yes somthing like that http://jsfiddle.net/x3a6frgx/2/.