# div disappears when hovering over it or it leaves a white space

Tags: css

I have asked this question before here [div disappears when hovering over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255401) and replacing margin with position relative fixed the problem but now I get white space
http://jsfiddle.net/x3a6frgx/3/ (note the space between div2 and the bottom border) how can I fix that?
**css code:**

```
#body {
    border-width: 10px;
    border-color: red;
    border-style: groove;
}

#image {
    display: block;
}
#div1 {
    transition: opacity 1s;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
    width: 100px;
}
#div1:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
#div2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `top`, use `margin-top` for `#div1`:

```
#div1 {
   transition: opacity 1s;
   background-color: red;
   opacity: 0;
   position: relative;
   margin-top: -20px;
   width: 100px;
}
```